# CSS wildcards with :first-child

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have an unwieldy chunk of css that I am using to set the margin-top of the first child of an element. The first child can be any tag.

```css
.comment-description  p:first-child,
.comment-description  ol:first-child,
.comment-description  ul:first-child,
.comment-description  pre:first-child,
.comment-description  blockquote:first-child
{
    margin-top:0px;    
}
```

I'm sure that I can chop this down, but since I don't get to design too often, I can't remember a better way. Can I use something like:

```css
.comment-description *:first-child
{
    margin-top:0px;    
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work.

Comment: Can you post your HTML?

Comment: May be interested in `.comment-description > :first-child {}`

Comment: I assume the missing comma after `pre:first-child` is unintended?

Comment: Just bad copy n paste. Fixed.

Comment: @Rob W I believe using > with :first-child is redundant as first-child implicitly applies only to immediate children.

Comment: No it doesn't. Without the child selector (`>`) it will select `first-children` from all levels. Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: @BlackKnight - I don't think so. http://jsfiddle.net/9VqsW/ but perhaps just `.comment-description :first-child` would work?

Comment: @Rob W You are right. Please post this as an answer. One Trick Pony - I didn't want all levels, but only the immediate children.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may be interested in:

`.comment-description > :first-child {}` - select only immediate children

or

`.comment-description :first-child` - select first child of all children elements

See:

http://jsfiddle.net/9VqsW/1/

Comment: Thanks. I think it's fair to acept Rob Ws answer as he came up with it first. I've upvoted other people who were helpful.

Comment: @Ozzy: what doesn't make sense? It selects the first direct descendant in its entirety. See jsfiddle link posted in answer for a few good examples.

Comment: Okay I was under the (incorrect) impression > only selects the first child node. It's fine, I +1'd now

Answer (score 1):

To clarify things a little:

- `.element selector` - selects all descendants that match `selector`. It doesn't matter if `selector` is a class, pseudo-class or ID.
- `.element > selector` - selects only on the direct children that match `selector`

It looks like you want:

```
.comment-description > :first-child{
   ....
}
```

Comment: Go back to your first answer - that worked. (.comment-description :first-child)

Comment: @shomz Can you explain?  I believe the original answer worked unless I'm missing some edge case somehow.

Comment: Hmm so my css was right?? I could swear it didn't work with one browser. I can't remember which one though, and now it works. Oh well :). Your answer is slightly better though.

Comment: What did you just do to your answer? if you have the `>` why do you need `:first-child` as well???

Comment: Because OP wants to select the first child element only?

Comment: So what do you think the `>` does?

Comment: Selects *all* children. Adding `:first-child` filters them down to the first one

Comment: My bad, looks like I'm a bit rusty too

Comment: @JamesMontagne I misread the question and believed that OP would want it to work for every child type (every first child of `p`, `ol`...etc, all the elements listed in the OP's question), multiple elements. Deleted my original comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
.comment-description :first-child
{
    margin-top:0px;    
}
```

Has the same effect as

```
.comment-description *:first-child
{
    margin-top:0px;    
}
```

Have a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vmarche/Lgr4f/).

Comment: I've read somewhere that the latter is much slower because the browser will first scan for all the elements, then match the ones that have `.comment-description` as parent or ancestor, then filter them by the `:first-child` selector...

Comment: Interesting. The former is the correct answer, but I wonder why the latter didn't work for the author of the question?

Comment: @One Trick Pony: `*` is implied in `:first-child`, so browsers would have to check every element either way.

Comment: [Here's the article](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/06/18/simplifying-css-selectors/) which states that the universal selector forces the browser to match all elements in the page before applying next rule (previous selector)

Comment: That article describes how browsers happened to behave in 2009. Browsers are free to implement any way they choose, as long as the results are correct, and as of 2017 that test page loads so fast in Chrome that the time is not measurable as it is below 1ms.